# Run Ubuntu 16.04 with RAID0 on XPS15 (dual boot with Win10)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

First, I'm very new to linux :).

I've just received a dell XPS 15 9550 running with Win10. I've decidedto jump ahead and install a dual boot Win10/Ubuntu 16.04. I've used a Live USB. Everything works well except one thing.

During the installation of Ubuntu, I had to switch my SATA parameters from RAID0 to AHCI (via the bios) since in RAID0, Ubuntu was unable to detect my hard drives / partitions.

At the moment, I'm still using AHCI.

- In AHCI, Ubuntu boots but Windows can't.
- In RAID0, Windows boots Ubuntu can't.

So everytime I want to switch from Windows to Ubuntu or vice versa, I need to go in the bios first to prevent non-booting. It's really annoying.

I'm not sure, is askubuntu the good place for this?

Thanks.